# Canopy doesn't start after seamless installation

Tags: python, enthought

I read almost every post on the subject on the forum, but I was not able to fix this annoying problem. I've a fresh Canopy 2.1.3 installation on Fedora 26. Nothing happens whether I try to execute it via GUI or command line ('canopy' is not recognized even as a command!).

I'm clueless, I suppose the issue may be with the environmental variables PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME (Fedora ships with its own Python distribution by RedHat), but I have not been able to fix the problem in the past two hours.
[Here](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469810-Windows-Canopy-shortcut-in-Start-menu-doesn-t-do-anything) is the reference from Enthought itself I'm referring to.

What puzzles me is that in the previous Fedora releases I did not experience such problems at all when executing Canopy for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

a) The article that you reference is Windows-specific, but certainly on any OS, PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME should never be be pointing to any Python distribution. See [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469160-How-do-I-set-PYTHONPATH-and-other-environment-variables-for-Canopy-).

b) If the `canopy` command is literally *not recognized* (vs being recognized but not starting as expected), then that at least is probably a generic "how do I start an executable?" issue, with typical answers being "Put its path in your PATH environment variable" or "reference the executable directly by its full path".